# How to check if the current Oracle DBMS is Enterprise version?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, macros, version

```
select * from v$version;
```

prints:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
...
```

Now, I would like to check if the current Oracle DBMS is Enterprise version (just Enterprise version without Release ect.)?

```
DECLARE
  VAR_CURRENTVERSION VARCHAR(500);
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO VAR_CURRENTVERSION FROM v$version;
  IF (VAR_CURRENTVERSION = 'ENTERPRISE_EDITION') THEN
    SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You have Enterprise Oracle Edition Version');
  ELSE
    SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You have Normal Oracle Edition Version');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Is in Oracle any macro like "ENTERPRISE_EDITION"?

Comment: No.  You can obviously do a `like` query against `v$version`.  You can put that check in your own function.  PL/SQL doesn't have the concept of a macro.  Be aware that there exist corner cases where the `v$version` data doesn't jive with what's actually installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic `ENTERPRISE_EDITION` macro or function. You might want to do something like the following:

```
DECLARE
  bIs_enterprise  BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  bIs_enterprise := FALSE;

  FOR aRow IN (SELECT BANNER
                 FROM V$VERSION
                 WHERE UPPER(BANNER) LIKE '%DATABASE%ENTERPRISE%')
  LOOP
    bIs_enterprise := TRUE;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Done in this manner `bIs_enterprise` will be TRUE if the database you're attached to is running an enterprise version, and FALSE if not.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have just an idea. Solution with cursors.

```
DECLARE
  cursor CUR_VERSION IS SELECT * FROM v$version;
  VAR_CURRENTVERSION VARCHAR(500);
  IS_ENTERPRISE_VERSION NUMBER;
BEGIN
  OPEN CUR_VERSION;
    FETCH CUR_VERSION into VAR_CURRENTVERSION;
  CLOSE CUR_VERSION;
  SELECT INSTR(VAR_CURRENTVERSION, 'Enterprise') INTO IS_ENTERPRISE_VERSION from dual;

  IF (IS_ENTERPRISE_VERSION > 0) THEN
    SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You have Enterprise Oracle Edition Version');
  ELSE
    SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You have Normal Oracle Edition Version');
  END IF;
END;
```